# Printing pointer addresses in C [two questions]

Tags: c, pointers, int, free, command-line-arguments

I know that my questions are very simple but googleing them didn't get me any useful results... They'r probably too simple!!

No. 1

```
char* createStr(){
    char* str1 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    printf("str1 address in memory : %p\n", &str1);
    return str1;
}

int main(void){
    char* str2 = createStr();
    printf("str2 address in memory : %p\n", &str2);
}
```

Result:

```
str1 address in memory : 0x7fffed611fc8
str2 address in memory : 0x7fffed611fe8
```

Why are the addresses different in and out of the createStr() function and how can I free(str1)???

No. 2

```
int main(int argc, int *argv[]){
    printf("Basename is %s ", (char*) argv[0]);
    if(argc > 1 ){
        printf("and integer arg is : %d.\n", (int) *argv[1]);
    }
}
```

If I compile and run `$ ./test 3`, how can I get int 3?

Result:

```
Basename is ./test and integer arg is : 1380909107.
```

Comment: One question per question, please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comments inline!

No. 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* createStr(){
    char* str1 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    /* str1 is a local variable which is allocated in 
       stack and not in heap */
    /* But the dynamic memory allocation is done in 
       heap so malloc returns a portion of memory from
       heap and str1 is made to point to that!
    */
    /*
    aaaa (stack)    bbbb (heap)
    +--------+      +-+-+-------+-+
    |  str1  |----->|0|1| ..... |9|
    +--------+      +-+-+-------+-+
    */

    printf("address of str1 in memory : %p\n", &str1);
    /* prints aaaa and not bbbb */
    /* to print the base address of the allocated memory, 
    printf("str1 address in memory : %p\n", str1);
    */
    printf("address of the allocated memory inside func : %p\n", str1);

    return str1;
}

int main(void){
    char* str2 = createStr();
    /* str2 is a local variable to main and so it is
       allocated in the stack 
    */
    /*
    cccc (stack)    bbbb (heap)
    +--------+      +-+-+-------+-+
    |  str2  |----->|0|1| ..... |9|
    +--------+      +-+-+-------+-+
    */
    printf("address of str2 in memory : %p\n", &str2);
    /* the above will print the address of the str2 
       (which is cccc) but not where it is pointing 
       to (bbbb) ..
    */
    /* So to print the base address of where it is 
       pointing to (bbbb), 
    printf("str2 address in memory : %p\n", str2);
    */
    printf("address of the allocated memory inside main : %p\n", str2);
}
```

No 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int atoi(char a[])
{
        int i, n=0;

        for (i=0 ; a[i] >= '0' && a[i] <= '9' ; i++)
                n = 10 *n + (a[i]-'0');

        return n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Basename is %s ", (char*) argv[0]);
    if(argc > 1 ){
        printf("and integer arg is : %d.\n", atoi(argv[1]));
    }
}


$ gcc atoi.c -o atoi
$ ./atoi 3
Basename is ./atoi and integer arg is : 3.
$
```

Point to note:

- w.r.t #2 : in main() it should be `char * argv[]` and not `int * argv[]`

Comment: @Psyclops: If this answers the question, mark it so. Click the 'tick', so to say.

Answer (score 5):

**To fix the first one:**

```
char* createStr(){
    char* str1 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    printf("str1 address in memory : %p\n", str1);
    return str1;
}

int main(void){
    char* str2 = createStr();
    printf("str2 address in memory : %p\n", str2);
    free(str2);
}
```

Otherwise, you're printing out the address of the *variable* (`str1` and `str2`), not the address the variable is pointing to.

I've also added a call to `free()` to fix the memory leak.

**As to the second one,** you need to use `atoi()` to convert the string to an `int`:

```
printf("and integer arg is : %d.\n", atoi(argv[1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1**:

The addresses are different because you are taking the addresses of the pointers, not the addresses of the variables held by the pointers. Since `str2` exists on the stack of `main` and `str1` on the stack of `createStr`, their addresses are different.

You can free `str1` by freeing `str2`, because they point the same location. The address that `str1` points to is copied inside `str2` when `str1` is returned from `createStr`.

**Question 2**:

Use `int value = atoi(argv[1]);` This converts a `char*` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The first example allocates the string, then returns a pointer to it. When you do the assignment from the method's return value, you just assign the pointer. You only ever made one string.

In the second example, you want `atoi`.

Answer (score 0):

For the second exemple : `*argv[1]` is a `char *`  (i.e  `"3"` )
If you want to display `"3"` you have to use `printf("%s\n", *argv[1]);` or get an integer from the string using `atoi()`.
Maybe you can even try to write your own version of `atoi()`!